# ocaml function takes tuple and tuple list return a tuple

Tags: ocaml

I have the following problems where my function take tuple and a list of pair and it should return a tuple but i got the error saying that

```
a is tuple contains (int*list) and x is list of pairs [(a1,b1).....(an,bn)]
```

what i want to do is the add two list together lets say I pass in `[9;9]` `[1;0;2]` then it should return a `[2;0;1]`, and im using the `list.fold_left` tail recursion to do it. this is the function i got confuse about,
I pass in the

```
list.fold_left f (0;[]) (List.combine(List.rev(l1),List.rev(l2))
```

so `a` should be a tuple contains `(int*list)`
x is list of pair

Answer (score 1):

When you use `List.fold_left` your function gets only one element of the list at a time. It looks to me like your function `f` is written to expect a list of things as `x`. But `x` will be just one pair (if I'm reading your code correctly).

**Edit**

Since you wrote your `f` as if `x` is a list, then when you use `List.fold_left` with `f`, you're in essence saying that its argument should be a list of lists. This is what the error message is telling you. If you rewrite `f` so that `x` is a pair (which is what you want, I'm pretty sure), this will fix the error.

Comment: the function f return a tuple ( int * list), can i ask what is this about? let (_, res) = List.fold_left f base args in 
      res

Comment: i think x is args which is a list of pair

Comment: Right, I'm saying it's not a list. It's a pair. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think so!  Regards,

Comment: but what is this talking about?     let (_, res) = List.fold_left f base args in res

Comment: It's saying that your function f is written as though `args` is going to be a list of lists. But `args` is just a list.

Comment: a list of list? like [ [1;2;3] ;[5;6;7]]

Comment: These comment's aren't for chatting back and forth (according to SO). See Edit in my answer.